# display random text from a list on submit from textarea

Tags: jquery, random, textarea, submit

I'd like to achieve the following:

I have a text area with an input ( Button type).

The user fill the text area, otherwise, on submit, the text which is being display ( in another div) should be different ( taken randomly from a list or other word ).

On the moment I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div clas="col-md-12">
        <form name="myForm">
Content to be added:
<textarea name="myContent">ADD YOUR NAME</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Add content" onClick="addContent('result', document.myForm.myContent.value); setCookie('content', document.myForm.myContent.value, 7);">
</form>
</div>
</div>

<script>

function addContent(divName, content) {
     document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
}

</script>
```

which make appear the text added in the area in my other div. I have just no idea of the path I should take to display another text fro a specific list randomly instead.

Any highlight, will be amazing !

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you 've tag your question with JQuery tag. So i'll respond you with a JQuery way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world! <span name="result"></span></h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div clas="col-md-12">
                <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
        Content to be added:
        <textarea name="myContent" id="myContent">ADD YOUR NAME</textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Add content" id="mySubmitBtn">
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        // DOM ready
        $(function(){
            myArray = ['toto', 'tutu', 'titi', 'me', 'her !! '];

            console.log("ready to work with Jquery");
            //listener on sumbit btn (ie : your old onclick function)
            $("#myForm").on("click","#mySubmitBtn", function(){
                Randomize();
                addContent('result', $("#myContent").val());
                //setCookie('content', document.myForm.myContent.value, 7);
            });

            Randomize = function(){
                var randomNbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
                if( $("#myContent").val() === ""){
                    $("#myContent").val(myArray[randomNbr]);
                }
            };

            function addContent(divName, content) {
                console.log('hello : '+content);
                $("[name='"+divName+"']").text(content);
            }
        });



    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see :

1. I create a bootstrap page so you can test my code
2. I have put ID on your input so it's easier to access them in JQuery
3. I create an array so you'll put your future pseudo (i guess)
4. I make a listener for your submit click event
5. I create a random function that put a pseudo in your input textearea if the textarea is empty !!

just copy code in a html file to test !!